# JProgressBar to keep track of a Native(C++) application using JNI

Tags: java, c++, swing, java-native-interface

I have a c++ application which runs for a long time and I want to track the progress of it. I have a user interface for this application in java. Can anyone please tell me how to track the progress of the native application using JProgressBar. My native application returns an integer when it is done and I have a "Done" button that shows up when this integer is returned. But I want to have a progress bar that shows that the native application is running.

Comment: is possible in the case that C++ via JNI/JNA returns process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said you need to have a way for your java application to know how far alone your c++ application is.

If you want a quick fix, use a JProgressBar and set it to interdeminate.  It will animate the bar to show you something is happening.  Once your process returns set the bar to 100%.

Easy way:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
Process p = processBuilder.start();

p.waitFor();
progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getMaxValue());
```

Better way:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = processBuilder.start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //error checking
       int progressValue = Integer.parseInt(line);
      progressBar.setValue(progressValue);
    } finally {
       in.close();
    }
}
progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getMaxValue());
```

Answer (score 4):

The only ways would be to either create a callback in java (meaning the code in c++ would call the java function) to inform of the current progress or create a function that the java code calls to get the current progress of your task.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI

The java code would then use the value to update the jprogress bar.

Comment: Thank you Adam Galarneau, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible simpler solution from Adam's is to have your C++ program output an update of progress to standard output, perhaps a String representation of the percent of progress. The Java program's Process would then have its OutputStream monitored by calling `getInputStream()` on the Process (yeah, it's not a typo; it's `getInputStream()`) in a thread background to the Swing thread, and use the information for updating the JProgressBar.

Comment: +1, a bit complicated for me, but quite fascinating. If I would do such a thingy, I feel like I knew __Java__ to the core :-) Though my vote will come in 8 hours :( , my limit is gone for the day...

Comment: +1 I (still) think than not limited to String value, sure maybe you're right EDIT, question is possible to read onclosed buffer (getInputStream() can be buffered)